# How can i change "this" class name with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, dom

I have a list of button with all latin-alphabet and i want to change the class name from "m_letter" to "m_letter active" for example so i can toggle them.

My javascript code is this

```
$(".m_letter").click(function(){
  $(this).className = "m_letter active"; //This is an example i tried other codes that i found on net.
});
```

Html

```
<li class="m_letter">A</li>
<li class="m_letter">B</li>
<li class="m_letter">C</li>
...
<li class="m_letter">Z</li>
```

Comment: You've conflated two different approaches. One is the native API, which would be `this.className = ...`, and the other is the jQuery API, which to use, one must construct a jQuery object that wraps your `this` element, and do `$(this).addClass(...`, where `.addClass()` is a method on jQuery object returned from the `$` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

This will add the class on click:

```
$(".m_letter").click(function(){   $(this).addClass('active'); });
```

If you need to remove the active class from a different m_letter first, add this line.

```
$('.m_letter.active').removeClass('active')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.addClass()`

```
$(this).addClass('m_letter active');
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery, it's easy:

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

inside your click handler.

Don't use:

```
$('.m_letter').addClass('active');
```

as that will set *all* of the items to active.

Comment: Well i tried it and it worked but whats the difference between addClass('active') and addClass('m_letter active') because both have the same result i think.

Comment: @Incognito Same result, but the second one is verbose. It’s enough to add the class you are actually adding.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this: http://jsfiddle.net/CKW25/1/

**JS**

```
$(".m_letter").click(function(){
   $(".m_letter").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass( "active" );
});
```